# Using array stored in session on remote machine

Tags: arrays, session

I have stored an array in a session, which I am sending to a function on a remote server. I am using these values to put in a remote database. My problem is the array is being sent, but it is empty.

Being sent

```
  <?php 
session_start();
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
$blah = $_SESSION['blah'];

$client = new nusoap_client( 'http://myserver.com/datatest.php'  );

$response = $client->call('myfunction', $blah); 

?>
```

At the remote server:

```
  <?php 
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');  





$server = new soap_server(); 





$server->register('myfunction');  





function myfuction ($blah) 

{ 
//MY DB CONNECTIONS
$row = $blah;



$count = count($row);

for($i=0;$i<=$count-1;$i++){

$value1 = '8';
$item = $i+1;

$first = $row[$i]['first'];
$second = $row[$i]['second'];


$time = date("His");
$month = date("m"); 
$day = date("d"); 
$year = date("y"); 
$julian = juliantojd($month, $day, $year);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `MYTABLE` (value1, item, first, second, time, julian) VALUES ('$value1', '$item', '$first', '$second', '$time', '$julian')";

return $code_showing_query;

}
}
?>
```

When I execute this, the varibles I set on the server (Item, Value1 etc... )insert into the database, but the first and second I am sending are emtpy.

I can return the $blah array I am sending, and it comes back with the values. The session of course is still in my browser, but I am losing it going to the remote server. I have tried the following: (Was sure it wasnt going to work, but I tried)

```
 <?php 
$blah = $_SESSION['blah'];
$blah = serialize($blah); 
$blah = base64_encode($blah);

//AT THE REMOTE SERVER
$blah = base64_decode($blah);
$blah = unserialize($blah);
?>
```

Basically, I need to find away to find away to make the array i'm getting from the session out of the session to send to the remote server, so it is not associated to a session. I have to keep everything in a session before this point, because this is a ordering system, and I have to post the final order to a remote iSeries.

I know it is something simple...just something I've not done and/or it is just stumping methanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem... It was something simple.

The call to the function on the server:

```
$response = $client->call('myfunction', $blah);
```

Should be this:

```
$response = $client->call('myfunction', Array($blah));
```

I was sending a multidiminsional array, and I the Array the server was looking for was a basic array looking like this:

```
Array ( [something] => 5555 [something] => 5555 [something] => 5555)
```

But I was sending this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [something] => 5555 [something] => 5555 [something] => 5555 ) )
```

The server saw:

```
Array ( [0] => Array // it ignored the rest of the array
```

After the changing this `$response = $client->call('myfunction', Array($blah));`

the server now is looking for:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [something] => 5555 [something] => 5555 [something] => 5555 ) )
```